# Git how to get the file from master

Tags: git, version-control

I tried `git pull` from master branch to fetch the changes

Then i get this error

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/scripts/core.js

Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Now i want to keep the server core.js file not my core.js. how can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a merge conflict... Open the file and fix the merge.

Scroll through `core.js`, find, and fix the conflict.

If you want to completely discard your changes, and take those only from the server, you could use `git checkout src/scripts/core.js`.

Comment: thanks for that. I could not get one thing. i had meld set as merge and diff tool, why didn't my meld window open

Comment: i get this error when i tried ur command `error: path 'src/symfony/web/scripts/app/common/utils.js' is unmerged`